# Как происходит валидация майнинга bitcoin?

Tags: теория, bitcoin, блокчейн

Представьте, что какой-то разработчик придумывает новый алгоритм по подбору sha или вообще вздумалось ему рандомизировать и тыкаться локально в проверку майнинг хэша
Какие средства уже существующие может использовать этот разработчик, чтобы:

1. Провалидировать локально свой новоиспеченный хэш
2. Как он сможет отправить это в сеть биткоин, есть ли для этого протокол?

Что из себя представляет майнинг хэш?

а. Он всё ещё должен быть красивым с ведущими нулями? Где информация об этом может быть прочитана

б. На основе чего он делается? Предыдущей транзакции? Но их же куча...

Comment: Пожалуйста, исправьте вопрос, чтобы он отражал конкретную проблему с достаточным количеством деталей для возможности дать адекватный ответ.

Comment: Если Ваш вопрос, о том: "Что будет если научаться находить данные из хеша за маленькое время", то да вся "безопасность" современного интернета улетит в никуда. А вообще, если вопрос об этом, то их нельзя задавать на `SO`

Answer (score 0):

Что бы корректно провалидировать свой хеш локально вам нужно знать текущую сложность сети. По простому сложность это количество ведущих нулей. Но корреткней говорить, что сложность это 256-битное число, и хеш который вы ищите должен быть меньше этого числа. (32-байтный хеш также можно представить как 256-битное число). Сложность пересчитывается раз в 2016 блоков. [Документация](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty).

Если вы включаете в свой блок чужие транзакции (а вы имеете полное право этого не делать, и включать только транзакцию на генерацию новых монет), то вам нужно локально хранить весь блокчейн и валидировать каждую транзакцию. Включите невалидную транзакцию, ваш блок никто не примет, и ваша работа по поиску хеша пойдет насмарку.

Что бы отправить свой блок другим узлам сети существует низкоуровневый протокол поверх TCP. [Документация](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Network).

Когда считается хеш блока, берется только заголовок блока длиной 80 байт. Среди этих 80 байт содержится:

- Хеш предыдущего блока. Таким образом блоки формируют неизменяюмую цепочку, отсюда и термин blockchain.
- Текущая сложность сети.
- Хеш от всех транзаций в текущем блоке (расчитан по алгоритму дерева Меркла).